# How to parse this string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to parse this string with python (maybe with re module) and create array with this data?

```
map: mp_rust
num score ping guid                             name            lastmsg address               qport rate
--- ----- ---- -------------------------------- --------------- ------- --------------------- ----- -----
```

Comment: What *output* do you expect? This looks like a header, are there more lines following these?

Comment: incomplete, please make it a real question

Comment: in ----- will be user's data

Comment: That sentence does not parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With fixed-width formatting, [string slicing](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) is likely the best way to parse:

```
num = s[0:3]
score = s[4:9]
ping = s[10:14]
guid = s[15:47]
name = s[48:63]
 ...
```

Be sure to [*strip*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) away excess whitespace and convert to [*int*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int) where necessary.

You can create an "array" of the results by storing them in a [list](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
arr = [num, score, ping, guid, name, lastmsg, address, qport, rate]
```

Comment: Unless "num" will always be "num" s[0:3] won't cut it. I would go with `s.split()[0]` and so.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the exact length of data (name could be "jack" or "theodore", just saying), so splitting at spaces could be a smarter approach. It is string slicing yet less static.

```
>>> s = 'num score ping guid                 name            lastmsg address'
>>> num, score, ping, guid, name, lastmsg, address = s.split()
```

If those values may contain spaces then you must go down with regexes.

Comment: Some comment would help. Perhaps I'm so wrong that not even a downvote will make me realize the problem. Would love to see the bigger picture. ;)